# Any action required? (Update PayPal Integration until 18. January 2017)

Tags: paypal, paypal-standard

I received an e-mail (see below) to update the paypal integration. I am not able to find any information through google. Did anyone else receive this email?

When I had a call with the paypal, they could not answer me if I need to make any changes since we use the standard paypal payment method on Magento already.

I unfortunately donot know if I need to take any action personally or this change should have been already reflected through Magento? We are running on Version 1.9.0.1

Any tips are highly aqppreciated.

> *Update your integration before 18 January 2017. 
>   Name Here, On 18 January 2017, we’ll be making some updates to make the checkout
>   process on Website Payments Standard even better, which means your
>   integration will be affected. We’ve noticed that your integration has
>   been passing either invalid or incorrect data to PayPal from one or
>   more of your payment buttons. To make sure your payments continue to
>   be processed, you’ll need to update your integration as soon as
>   possible. Here are some of the benefits you’ll receive with your
>   updated integration: • PayPal One Touch™, our fastest, easiest
>   checkout experience enabling your shoppers to check out at the click
>   of a button • A mobile-optimised checkout experience, so buying is
>   easy no matter how your customers shop • A new, simpler design that is
>   consistent across both desktop and mobile What do you need to do?
>   Please check out these FAQs for more information on common integration
>   issues. Additional details can be found in our developer documentation
>   here. When you’ve updated your integration, your customers will see
>   the updated experience. As always, if you need help or have any
>   questions, call us or visit our Help Centre.*

Comment: Please, check this official FAQ: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ2067